# What is a better way to structure my code here?

Tags: java, android

I'm a newbie trying to write an app which input/outputs a number between 1-10 after pressing a button. I'm hoping to have this code throw an exception when the input value is outside the 1-10 boundary.

> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

I believe it has to do with the way I put my rand() function inside the onClick() listener. Am I on the right track that it's just written very poorly?

Thanks very much if you can help.

Here is my code:

> ```
> public Button button;
> public TextView textView;
> public EditText editText;
> Random r;
> public int max=0;
> public int min=0;
> public int temp=0;
>
>
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>     button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
>     editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
>     editText.setText("");
>     textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
>
> }
>
> public void onClick(View view) {
>
>     rand(Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString()));
>
>
>     }
>
>
> public void rand(int temp) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException{
>
>
>
>     temp = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
>     if(temp >10 || temp<0){
>         throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("out of bounds... between 1-10");
>     }
>     if(!editText.equals("")){
>         min = 10-temp;
>         max = r.nextInt(min + 1)+1;
>
>     }
>     String set = String.valueOf(max);
>
>     textView.setText(set);
>
> }
> ```

Also, here is my XML

> ```
> <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
>     android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
>     android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
>
> </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/textView"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_row="1"
>     android:layout_column="0"
>     android:layout_columnSpan="0"
>     android:text="Enter a Number Between 1 and 10:"
>     android:textSize="30sp" />
>
> <EditText
>     android:id="@+id/editText"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_row="2"
>     android:layout_column="0"
>     android:ems="10"
>     android:inputType="number" />
>
> <Button
>     android:id="@+id/button"
>     android:layout_width="369dp"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_row="3"
>     android:layout_column="0"
>     android:layout_columnSpan="2"
>     android:text="Button"
>     android:onClick="onClick"
>     android:textSize="30sp" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/output"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_row="4"
>     android:layout_column="0"
>     android:text="output"
>     android:textSize="30sp" />
> ```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: The test `!editText.equals("")` looks fishy.  Don't you mean `!editTextgetText().equals("")`?  But even then it's fishy that you perform that test only *after* trying to parse the text to an integer.  What do you suppose happens if the text does not have the form of an integer?

Comment: Some remarks on your code: almost all attributes of the shown class are `public`, breaking encapsulation. This is considered a code smell. --- The methods `public void onClick(View)` and `public void rand(int)` do not use their parameters or the parameters could be local variables. You should fix that. --- Your code format is a little bit messy: Your indentation is not consistent, you use too many blank lines and you use inconsistent formation rules (sometimes, binary operators have no blanks at all, sometimes only on the left side).

Answer (score 0):

U have to put your function call into a try/catch block:

```
public void onClick(View view) {

try{
  rand(Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString()));
}catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The OP is a bit unclear on this point, but I think he's claiming that no, he *wants* to throw an exception (from `onClick()`).